# Difference between Chrome and Firefox addons ? (Developers Point of view)

Tags: browser

I have been using Firefox for since year or two as web developer and i love it, cant think of someone else because of its handy addons

Now google Chrome also support addons can someone tell me difference ? Which one is best you think ? Why should i use Chrome over Mizilla ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Google Chrome extensions (and Mozilla's new [Jetpack](http://mozillalabs.com/jetpack/)) you only have to know html, javascript & css whereas for full-blown firefox addon's there's [XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL) to be mastered.

That being said, there is functionality that can't be implemented in Chrome extensions or Jetpacks (yet), which can be done in Firefox addons. Giorgo Maone of NoScript-fame for example [explains on his blog what is missing in Chrome extensions](http://hackademix.net/2009/12/10/why-chrome-has-no-noscript/) for NoScript to be ported.

Comment: Also here is useful post about differences: http://blog.nparashuram.com/2011/10/writing-browser-extensions-comparing.html

Answer (score 0):

By far [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/1843) and [web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/60) in firefox was really the best addons i used... I miss lot of firebug features in google chrome..

I got more control over **jquery** using both the addons...

One Cons was Whenever you gets the updates of Firefox (for only browser),most of the time there is chance of incompatibility of any of your favourite add-on.